# Heating Element (resistor) to maintain temperatures in the 80-150°F in an incubator

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, circuit-design, heat

I would like to maintain temperatures anywhere from 80-150°F inside of an incubator (an augmented cooler).

Yogurt ferments at 110°F, Bacillus subtilis at 100°F, certain sprouts do well at certain temperatures, etc.

I can easily whip up the scripts to control a relay based on a temperature sensor.

What I need help with is picking the heating element scheme. I am interested in making nichrome coils, or cupronickel is also on my mind. I understand that what I need are VERY low temperatures, but does not that imply only that I need very low voltages? (yes i know, current is what dictates the heat produced by a resistor, but of course that depends on the supply voltage)

Would DC power be applicable? Can I use the power available from my microcontroller? Am I crazy?

Comment: 80°F isn't a very low temperature unless you spend most of your time living on venus

Comment: I think your first job is to figure out how much power you need to maintain the highest internal temperature... at the lowest external temperature.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a chassis mount power resistor or similar type as a heater. You will need to **size** the heater- typically one might figure out how much power is required to maintain the highest temperature you need, at the lowest ambient temperature expected, and then (say) double that power. Here is an example resistor from [this](http://www.electronicsurplus.com/vishay-dale-electronics-rh25-10r-resistor-power-10-ohm-25w) surplus dealer (but you can buy them from a distributor in pretty much any value you need):

[image]

The voltage does not matter much, provided you have a supply available. Something like 12VDC would be safer for you to work with.

You might try a small incandescent light bulb of known wattage in the enclosure when it is complete to get an ideal of what power is required.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to maintain consistent temperatures, I'd recommend using a thermal reservoir (high heat capacity) and then heating the reservoir directly while passing low-velocity air over the top.  Have your sensor directly attached to the reservoir but out of the airflow.

Depending on the size of your incubator, your reservoir could be as simple as a few gallons of water.  Use a submersible heating element (maybe scavenge from an old electric kettle) and insulate the bottom of the water container and seal the top (you don't want to add humidity).  Make sure that the top has a high thermal conductivity.  You could even add a few fins from an old CPU heatsink to tighten your control loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use DC or any heat source. The energy required to heat depends on the energy lost in the oven.

I made a portable oven which I designed with a CPU fan crushed Dry Ice or a 35W solder iron suspended in air inside a plastic cooler to regulate the temperature from -40 to +70'C.

I suggest you work with 'C as 'F is not linear with Thermal resistance.

For about $30 you can instrument your range or make a portable cooler operate at any temp.  The trick is multiple temp sensors and force air circulation.

[image]

If you have a digital Home Thermostat and relocate the Thermistor inside the oven with short twisted pair, then you can regulate it to 1'F or 'C accuracy or perhaps +/-0.5 depending on brand.

It may take up 30 minutes to rise 10'C to the set-point temperature depending on the mass that has to be heated. but 1 or 2 small CPU fans are need to remove any thermal gradients inside the oven.  I suggest you have 2 thermistors, one for air temp and one for container temp using adhesive tape. How you accomplish this can be easily solved.

With some experimentation on location and mounting fans near the lid you can have it up and running in hours with moderate skills or spend weeks if you wanted. I did it in <1 hour and ran it for the whole day each day for a short term project.